How to Convert Camera Calibration Data to Specific Format?
I have camera calibration data in the following format from OSDaR23 dataset::
{
    "streams": {
        "intrinsics_pinhole": {
            "camera_matrix": [
                7265.854580654392, 0.0, 2093.506452810741, 0.0, 0.0,
                7265.854580654392, 1228.255759518024, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0
            ],
            "distortion_coeffs": [-0.0655375, -0.329857, 0.0, 0.0, 2.48002],
            "width_px": 4112,
            "height_px": 2504
        }
    },
    "coordinate_systems": {
        "rgb_highres_right": {
            "type": "sensor",
            "parent": "base",
            "pose_wrt_parent": {
                "translation": [0.0510683, -0.525541, 3.51628],
                "quaternion": [0.0217394, 0.0639103, -0.182324, 0.980918]
            }
        }
    }
}


I need to convert it to the following format:
{
    "extrinsic": [
        0.03564000242115317,
        0.9978643295462211,
        -0.05474093574913458,
        0.10951525717973709,
        -0.009726211086240999,
        -0.054426799113952706,
        -0.998470392328243,
        -0.003179325256496668,
        -0.9993173625257024,
        0.03611790909618268,
        0.007765667852400182,
        -0.39152929186820984,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        1
    ],
    "intrinsic": [
        1210.062981,
        0,
        1022.429903,
        0,
        1205.850714,
        792.541644,
        0,
        0,
        1
    ]
}

How to map my current camera_matrix format to the required intrinsic and extrinsic matrix format?
Additional Information:
The calibration data from the OSDaR23 dataset includes extrinsic parameters (translation and quaternion) describing the transformation from the lidar to the non-optical camera coordinate system. The non-optical system’s axes are aligned similarly to the lidar, while the optical system’s axes are aligned to the image coordinate system.

you'd need to have the definitions of those formats. you could have differently defined distortion models, which may be hard to "convert".

Maybe this will help:  https://segments.ai/blog/simulating-cameras-three-js

@ChristophRackwitz we can ignore distortion? only extrinsic intrinsic is required
